# PHP and Apache not compatible

Tags: php, apache, wamp, version

Iam try to install (switch) PHP v5.1.6 with last version of Wamp, but a console message says: "This PHP version doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual Apache Version. Switch cancelled..."

How I can know the apache version compatible with the php version indicated (5.1.6)? What is the procedure to downgrade the version current version of apache?

THX

Comment: What version of WAMPServer have you installed?

Comment: Wamp 2.4 = Apache 2.4.4 , PHP 5.4.12 and MySql 5.6.12

Answer (score 1):

PHP5.1.anything will not run with Apache 2.4.anything.

If you look in the PHP5.1.6 folder you will NOT see a php5apache2_4.dll, which is PHP for that version compiled as a DLL with linkages to Apache 2.4, all you will see is a `php5apache2_2.dll` i.e. that version of PHP compiled with Apache 2.2 linkages. Its possible that version of PHP only has linkages for Apache 2.0, in which case it could be a real pain trying to get it working.

So you will also have to install a Apache2.2 or maybe Apache 2.0 that will run with it.

Both Apache and PHP will need to be compiled with the same compiler, probably VC6, as I think PHP5.1 was almost definitely compiled with VC6.

You may also find it useful to install another version of PHP like PHP5.3.29 maybe as this will run under Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4, then when you are switching versions you can step backwards like so :-

```
While running Apache2.4 and PHP 5.4.16
Switch to PHP 5.3.29
Then switch to Apache 2.2.?
Then switch from PHP 5.3.29 to 5.1.6
```

***This assumes PHP5.1.6 runs with Apache 2.2 and does not need the extra steps to ge back to Apache 2.0***

You may also need other PHP's or Apache's I am not absolutely sure as its a long ways back from PHP5.4 to PHP5.1, but I hope this gives you a bit of an idea what might be involved.

Alternatively you could backup your current WAMPServer and uninstall it, and install an old version of WAMPServer 2.2a/b/c/d/e... You will have to try a few to see if they go back that far